# How to add a table to a Webform or EntityForm

Tags: webforms, entities

I am using a Drupal 7, and I want to have a customized form which includes:

1. Simple questionnaire with textfield, checkboxes and dropdown lists.
   (I am able to configure this part of the form)
2. The same form includes a table with multiple rows and columns where users can enter their data. I am not able to configure this.

I tried webform module + webform table module, but I am not getting the expected result. Then I tried entityform module(a better module than webform) but I am not able to configure a table.

Please suggest me a way to include a dynamic table in my customized form through entityform module or any other module.

Comment: Have you looked at [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)? As nearly as I can understad the requirement this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: i have this module installed, bt i have nt worked with it yet...plzz giv me kinda step byt step instructions or just an overview to use VBO...plzz plzzzzzz

Comment: Do you have any screenshot, it is better to understand your needs

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to achieve. see this link may be it helps you http://drupal.org/project/slickgrid

Comment: specifically this is what i want :

Comment: am using a Drupal 7, and i want to have a customized form which includes: 1. simple questionnaire with textfield , checkboxes and dropdown lists. (This part of the form i am able to configure) 2. The same form includes a table with multiple rows and columns where users can enter their data, this i am not able to configure.

I tried webform module+ webform table module, bt i am nt getting the expected result, then i tried entityform module(a better module than webform) but i am nt able to configure a table

please suggest me a way to include a dynamic table in my customized form

Answer (score 2):

A combination of [EntityForms](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) and [TableField](http://drupal.org/project/tablefield) should get you going.

> This module allows you to attach tabular data to a node in Drupal 6 or
>   any entity in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

As [Triskelion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13840/triskelion) suggests you can use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed
>   on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of
>   each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be
>   applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

[Read documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1591342) OR [Screencast](http://www.youtube.com/embed/uu8KkdjPucM) OR [VBO for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1591352)

Comment: I'm pretty sure VBO is not what is being looked for here.  VBO would allow you to perform operations on the result set provided the report was built in Views.  It doesn't, however, get a table *into* the form.  Unless I'm getting confused with the question, obviously.